# ASP.NET combo box not displaying correctly when using AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, layout

I have a website being built that uses Ajax to create a list of suggestions for an ASP.NET autocomplete combo box. I have gotten it to populate correctly, however when I run the site it looks like this:
[image]

I have moved the combo box to the bottom of the table and the drop down elements are still displayed with a gap approx. the size of three entries below where I would expect it to be displayed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to add <br/> between your combobox and First.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem was that it turns out the combo box was in a div with the position set to relative, which messes with the positioning of the the div that Ajax puts the drop-down-list in. 
Removing the the positioning element from the div fixed the problem just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1423235.aspx/1 .  It seems to match your problem description.  The solution is posted here: http://forums.asp.net/post/3173141.aspx

Answer (score 0):

the Problem is the site is being built in ASP.Net and the combo box is being pulled in from a control. There is no JS file for it